Count of pages found in google search
I am looking for the count of pages where search term "indieea" is found. Visited this page:
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22indieea%22
Goto the last page in search results. You get this line...
we have omitted some entries very similar to the 64 already displayed.

The function should return 64 because there are 64 pages for the given search term "indieea".
The code that I tried:
import asyncio
import urllib.parse
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright  # 1.44.0

async def main():
    term = urllib.parse.quote_plus("टंकलेखन")
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={term}"

    async with async_playwright() as pw:
        browser = await pw.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto(url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")

        # Find the <a> tag with aria-label="Page 9" and class="fl"
        link_element = page.locator('a[aria-label="Page 9"].fl').first
        if await link_element.count() > 0:  # Check if the element exists
            # Get the outerHTML of the element to print the full source code of the link
            link_html = await link_element.evaluate('el => el.outerHTML')
            print("Source code of the link:", link_html)
        else:
            print("Element not found.")

        await browser.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


Because $5 per 1000 queries for API is costly. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

A binary search-esque algorithm might be more efficient? Check page 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ... until something fails, then backtrack and fine the specific page that it failed on. I don't know if this is possible, but OpenSearch does specify a startIndex parameter. Also, I don't do a lot of google stuff, so...

Just replace the term variable in the code with "indieea". I need to return whatever approximate number google returns. I am OK with <10 or >100 result.

No. It is based on another stackoverflow question. <== Which you also wrote, and is clearly generated by AI, right?

All programming methods I've tried so far return 12 or 15 results on the first page, not 64.

Also, I don't see the line you mentioned either when I did a manual search. Perhaps it's some settings issue?

There's simply no such line by using either algorithms or manual search.

Not sure if this is contributing anything but if you press the "tools" button on Google you can see how many results there are found. If you use your search term with "", it will look for precise matches. Im seeing 913 hits.
In fact, this datapoint is in the returned html and you can search the returned page for:
document.getElementById("result-stats").innerText

or via your favorite python html parsing package.
At the moment this returns:
About 918 results (0.21 seconds)


Can you automate pressing tools button in python script?

There are some ways to do this. I'll list the two best ways here:

Use the googlesearch python API:

import googlesearch as gsearch


query = 'indieea'

for i, u in enumerate(gsearch.search(query, lang='en')):
    print(i, u)

print(f'query "{query}" returns {i} results') # outputs: query "indieea" returns 144 results


You can also add the stop, start, pause, or num parameters. Here's a brief overview of what those parameters do:

stop: Stop searching when reaching index stop.
start: Only return results after index start.
pause: Wait interval between searches.
num: The number of urls every  every "search" returns. By default, the library returns 10 urls every time, continuing until the results are depleted or reaching stop.


Use the serpapi python API:

from serpapi import GoogleSearch
query = "indieea"
search = GoogleSearch({
    "q": "indieea",
    "api_key": "<your api key>"
  })
result = search.get_dict()
print(f'query "{query}" returns {len(result)} results')

You do need to register a personal account for this approach to work though, but there's a free option. After registering, fetch your own personal API key from the website and replace "<your api key>" with it.
You can also create a .env environment file in the directory, with the line SERPAPI_KEY=<your api key>, and load the .env file using the os library.
